# get escaped unicode code from string

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

I seem to be having the opposite issue as everyone else in the development world. I need to generate escaped characters from strings. For instance, say I have the word `MESSAGE:`, I need to generate:

```
\\u004D\\u0045\\u0053\\u0053\\u0041\\u0047\\u0045\\u003A\\u0053\\u0069\\u006D
```

The closest thing I could get using Python was:

```
u'MESSAGE:'.encode('utf16')
# output = '\xff\xfeM\x00E\x00S\x00S\x00A\x00G\x00E\x00:\x00'
```

My first thought was that I could replace `\x` with `\u00` (or something to that effect), but I quickly realized that wouldn't work. What can I do to output the escaped (unescaped?) string in Python (preferably)?

**Before everyone starts "answering" and down voting**, the escaped `\u00...` string is what my app is getting from another 3rd party app which I have no control over. I'm trying to generate my own test data so I don't have to rely on that 3rd party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this (quick & dirty) code does what you want:

```
''.join('\\u' + x.encode('utf_16_be').encode('hex') for x in u'MESSAGE:')
# output: '\\u004d\\u0045\\u0053\\u0053\\u0041\\u0047\\u0045\\u003a'
```

Or if you want more '\':

```
''.join('\\\\u' + x.encode('utf_16_be').encode('hex') for x in u'MESSAGE:')
# output: '\\\\u004d\\\\u0045\\\\u0053\\\\u0053\\\\u0041\\\\u0047\\\\u0045\\\\u003a'
print _
# output: \\u004d\\u0045\\u0053\\u0053\\u0041\\u0047\\u0045\\u003a
```

If you absolutely need upper-case for hexadecimal codes:

```
''.join('\\u' + x.encode('utf_16_be').encode('hex').upper() for x in u'MESSAGE:')
# output: '\\u004D\\u0045\\u0053\\u0053\\u0041\\u0047\\u0045\\u003A'
```

Comment: you have restored my faith in the French. Thanks so much. Now I must decipher what all this stuff does

Comment: Well let me ask this then. How did you know to do those encodes? I don't even know where to even begin to research this topic (of encoding).

Comment: They are called "codecs". You'll find help there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Answer (score 2):

Pierre's answer is nearly right, but the `for x in u'MESSAGE:'` bit would fail for characters above U+FFFF, except for ‘narrow builds’ (primarily Python 1.6–3.2 on Windows) which use UTF-16 for Unicode strings.

On ‘wide builds’ (and in 3.3+ where the distinction no longer exists), `len(unichr(0x10000))` is `1` not `2`. When this code point is UTF-16BE-encoded you get two surrogates taking up four bytes, so the output is `'\\uD800DC00'` instead of what you probably wanted, `u'\\uD800\\uDC00'`.

To cover it on both variants of Python you can do:

```
>>> h = u'MESSAGE:\U00010000'.encode('utf-16be').encode('hex')
# '004d004500530053004100470045003ad800dc00'
>>> ''.join(r'\u' + h[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(h), 4))
'\\u004d\\u0045\\u0053\\u0053\\u0041\\u0047\\u0045\\u003a\\ud800\\udc00'
```

Comment: Thanks. I do see the importance of your answer, but I don't have chars above u+FFFF (from what I can tell atleast). So for my needs Pierre's code is sufficient. Best I can do is upvote your answer.

Comment: Yep, this is more an additional comment (but too big to go in a comment!)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go through the .encode() step if you don't have characters outside the BMP (>0xFFFF):

```
>>> ''.join('\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(a)) for a in u'Message')
'\\u004d\\u0065\\u0073\\u0073\\u0061\\u0067\\u0065'
```

Comment: I may have spoken too soon about not needing chars out side of BMP (>u+ffff). Although our app doesn't support it, it is possible that my app can receive msgs outside of BMP. So something like `u'\xf3'` (== ó) can wreak havoc on my side. So I may have to change my answer to the one provided by bobince.